# Name matching using spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a very huge customer data on HDFS with metadata but looking at the column names we cannot tell that which column contains what data(for e.g. customer name, card no, phone, email, address).

I also cannot peek into the data to check the type of data.

my task is to implement a model where i am able to find out the type of sensitive data each column contains there after masking the data. we have masking rules for each type of sensitive data.

If we talk about only name, then how i can find out which column contains name of the customers.

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: update your question with more details and be specific with your needs.

Comment: Sorry guys, question is what approach should i take to accomplish the task?

Comment: You should form an assumption that particular column will contain name of the customers. I recommend you to look at some sample data and do the assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You need to find the Column Name in spark you can use this

```
df.printSchema()
```